# What evil happens when somebody steals my release key for android apps?

Tags: android, google-play, key, sign

Before being able to publish an Android App on Google Play it needs to be signed with a release key. Its said to be for security. When generating the key one has to enter a password.

What is all the fuss about, here?
Let me ask, what would happen if my release key got stolen/copied. Assume somebody could even manage to use that key to sign apps of him/herself. What bad would that mean?

I would argue, little to none, correct? (considering that my developer account/console credentials were not stolen too)
Maybe the biggest/ only risk would arrise if somebody elses app signed with the stolen release key would become able to more directly access data of my app (on the users devices).

Comment: CommonsWare gives the result, but if u want to know the mechanics, see private/public key encryption.  You distribute the public key by signing, which is then used to determine if a new version came from a holder of the private key.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They can grab your APK (publicly readable on all Android devices), modify it (e.g., add malware), sign it, and distribute it. Assuming that they bump the `versionCode`, anyone who tries installing their hacked version of your app will succeed, as from Android's standpoint, it is a valid upgrade. If the hacker can obtain your credentials for your distribution channel (e.g., compromise your Google account for the Play Store), they can ship their update to all of your users.

Or, they can create their own separate APK and sign it with your signing key. Now, your app and theirs are signed by the same key. That opens up other attack avenues:

- If you used `android:sharedUserId`, they can get at all of your app's files on internal storage, which are normally protected from other apps (outside of rooted devices)
- If you used permissions with a `signature` `protectionLevel`, their app can hold those same permissions and perhaps interact with your app in ways that you were only expecting your own suite of apps to use

Comment: Even without the release key they could do the very same, that is they could still grap the APK, they could modify(malware) it and they could redistribute it, using a newly created release key anyway. So where did the situaiton get worse? To redistribute meaningfully, they would anyway have my google developer console account stolen too.

Comment: @humanityANDpeace: Android will not consider it to be an upgrade for existing app users. So, if the hacker got your distribution credentials, they could not distribute an update to all of your users. Think of it as being a two-factor authentication of sorts for app update distribution: an attacker needs something you have (your release keystore) and something you know (e.g., your Google account credentials).

Comment: Yes, there is a little sense to be seen (two factor), and also the point with accessing app internals (i.e. sharing access in between apps with the same release key) makes the release key not completely pointless.